# How to install cv2-modul

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, video

I use Python 3.8.7 and in my python-script I want to:
`import cv2`
This modul is not included in the standard-package. I tried:
`prompt>PIP install cv2`
but an error occured.
What can I do to install and use the modul cv2?

Comment: pip install opencv-python

Comment: Thanks, it works!